# AJaX: jQuery no envía los datos al archivo PHP que ha de insertarlos en MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, jquery, ajax

Siguiendo con la chapa que os doy con mi web musical, estoy intentando enviar datos vía AJaX/jQuery a mi base de datos; en concreto, las votaciones que los usuarios hagan a través de un radiobotón que acompaña a las canciones.

El radiobotón es el siguiente:

```
<div class="row"> <!-- Sistema de votación -->

    <span class="estrellas mt-3 ml-2">

        <?php 

            if($_SESSION['conectado']) for($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) 
            {
                echo '<input type="radio" name="'.$id_cancion.'" value="'.$i.'"';
                echo ($i == $nota) ? " checked><i></i>" : "><i></i>";  
            }

        ?>

    </span>

</div>
```

Si el usuario está registrado y conectado, puede votar de 1 a 5 cada canción, y para ello he escrito este script de jQuery; la verdad es que esto de AJaX me desconcierta un poco y las referencias que encuentro por internet son muchísimos más complejas que mi código, que he dejado en lo mínimo que puedo entender:

```
$(function() 
{
    $('input[type=radio]').change(function()
    {
        var voto = $(this).val();
        var idCancion = $(this).attr('name');
        var cancion = $(this).parents('.row').siblings('.row').find('.cancion').html();
        var autor = $(this).parents('.row').siblings('.row').find('.autor-recopilatorio').html();

        $.ajax(
        {
            type: 'POST', url: 'votacion.php', data: {voto: voto, id_cancion: idCancion},
            success: function()
            {
                if(voto == 5) swal("¡Guau!", "¡Amor a primera vista!", "success");
                else if(voto == 4) swal("¡Genial!", `¡Disfruta de ${autor}!`, "success");
                else if(voto == 3) swal(":)", "Buena canción, ¿eh?", "success");
                else if(voto == 2) swal("Vaya...", `¿No te convence ${cancion}?`, "warning");
                else swal("Bueno...", "No a todo el mundo le puede gustar lo mismo...", "error");
            },
            error: function()
            {
                swal("Vaya...", "Parece que tu voto no se ha podido enviar", "error");
            }
        })
    })
});
```

Bien, el script funciona en el sentido de que los modales se comportan como espero de ellos (uso una librería llamada SweetAlert): hay "success"...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero no llega nada a mi archivo `votacion.php` (es un primer boceto, en cuanto consiga pasarle los datos lo iré mejorando):

```
<?php

    session_start();

    foreach($_POST as $clave => $valor) $$clave = $valor;

    $id_usuario = $_SESSION['id_usuario'];

    include("conexion.php");

    $sql = "SELECT nota FROM votan WHERE id_usuario = $id_usuario AND id_cancion = $id_cancion";

    $resultados = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
    print_r($resultados);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($resultados) != 1)
    {
        mysqli_free_result($resultados);
        unset($sql);

        $sql = "INSERT INTO votan(id_usuario, id_cancion, nota) VALUES($id_usuario, $id_cancion, $nota)";

        $resultados = mysqli_query($conexion, $SQL);
    }
    else
    {
        mysqli_free_result($resultados);
        unset($sql);

        $sql = "UPDATE votan SET nota = $nota WHERE id_usuario = $id_usuario AND id_cancion = $id_cancion";

        $resultados = mysqli_query($conexion, $SQL);
    }

    mysqli_close($conexion);

?>
```

Si le añado algo de código para hacer verificaciones obtengo lo siguiente:

```
print_r($_POST);
```

Array ( )

```
print_r($_SESSION);
```

Array ( [conectado] => Administrador [id_usuario] => 1 )

```
echo $sql;
```

SELECT nota FROM votan WHERE id_usuario = 1 AND id_cancion =

Bien, como se puede comprobar `$_POST` parece no recibir nada; o quizá es que AJaX es tan rápido que no he de ver nada por pantalla, no lo sé. También recibo los siguientes mensajes de error, que entiendo son provocados porque no se pasa nada vía `$_POST`, aunque como he dicho esto es un boceto inicial y no he comprobado si el resto de la lógica es la apropiada:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intuyo que el problema tiene que ver con `data: {voto: voto, id_cancion: idCancion},`; he probado con otras formas de enviar datos, concatenándolos, pero no me ha funcionado de ninguna manera.

Gracias por adelantado.

Comment: Aparentemente la función `AJAX` la tienes bien montada. Lo que yo haría sería asegurarme de que estás llamando correctamente desde la misma al archivo **PHP**. Para ello eliminaría todo de este y colocaría solamente un `echo "ENTRA";`, por poner algo y luego en el `success` de la llamada `AJAX` añade como parámetro una variable para poder capturar la respuesta del **PHP**, quedando algo así: `success: function(respuesta)`. Por último un `console.log(respuesta)` y verificas si te devuelve el `echo`.

Comment: Intenta esto, abre la consola de desarrollador del sitio web y te vas a RED. haz la votacion y mira si la peticion te retorna 200, si es asi, esta llegando a tu archivo PHP de lo contrario, no esta llegando. Ahi tambien puedes ver los parametros que envias en la petición.

Comment: Desde la consola del navegador veo que está llegando la información, así que debe de ser un problema de `votacion.php`. El problema es que al cargar el propio archivo en el navegador da a entender que no está recibiendo la información, no sé por qué, y por eso no me había molestado en revisar más partes del código.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo he solucionado: no era un problema con AJaX, que funcionaba perfectamente, sino con PHP; a través del navegador daba la impresión de no estar recibiendo nada, pero a través de la consola pude ver que sí. El problema eran dos pequeños despistes: no existía la variable `$nota`, sino que era `$voto`, y la consulta era `$sql` y no `$SQL` (problemas del copia-pega).

Un saludo y gracias.